# Java for loop is hard to understand

Tags: java, loops

May someone explain to me why the following blocks of code generate such different outputs?

```
public class hello 
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int a,b,c;
        for (a  = 0; a < 5; a++)
        {
            for (b = 4; b >= a; b--)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (c = 0; c <= a - b; c++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

```
public class hello 
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int a,b,c;
        for (a  = 0; a < 5; a++)
        {
            for (b = 4; b >= 0; b--)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (c = 0; c <= a - b; c++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Shouldnt the outputs be the same since b >= a is equivalent to b >= 0 as b's value will be deducted by 1 for every loop?

Comment: These are nested loops, for each value a from 0 to 4 (smaller than 5), you loop over each value from 4 to a (first time that be 0, then 1, then 2, etc)

Comment: And when `a == 1` or `a == 2`? its not the same as `a == 0`

Comment: I thought b would have new value for each loop as b-- is there and that would mean the loop would be smaller every time... so it does nothing in this case?

Comment: Here in first program b is dependent to a so spaces are printed in decreasing order in each line . But in second program b is same throughout the loop but c is dependent to a so it printed 'star' in increasing order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the outputs cannot be the same, since every time you are executing

```
for (a = 0; a < 5; a++)
```

this gets executed as well (5 times)

```
for (b = 4; b >= a; b--)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
```

But the value of `a` is changing with every iteration: `a` will be initially 0, then 1, 2, 3 and finally 4.

Hence, the number of spaces that you are printing in the first scenario will decrease with every iteration of `a`.

> For a = 0 we have:
>       b = 4,
>       b = 3,
>       b = 2,
>       b = 1,
>       b = 0 (`for loop` stops since b=-1 is not >= a=0)
>
> For a = 1 we have:
>       b = 4,
>       b = 3,
>       b = 2,
>       b = 1 (`for loop` stops since b=0 is not >= a=1)
>
> For a = 2 we have:
>       b = 4,
>       b = 3,
>       b = 2 (`for loop` stops since b=1 is not >= a=2)
>
> For a = 3 we have:
>       b = 4,
>       b = 3 (`for loop` stops since b=2 is not >= a=3)
>
> For a = 4 we have:
>       b = 4 (`for loop` stops since b=3 is not >= a=4)

Comment: I thought b would have new value for each loop as b-- is there and that would mean the loop would be smaller every time, and that would be the same as for the first block of code... so in this case the b-- does nothing, and b still have the same value for every loop?

Comment: b will start every time at value 4, but the loop will be smaller because the condition `b >= a` will be false `earlier`, with the increase of `a` from the first `for` loop.

Comment: I was pretty confused as the b-- is there but the value of b stays the same through out the loop, so now i know that it does not change the value of b. Thanks!

Comment: I edited my post to make it more clear: the value of `b` does change during the loop in which it is used as index due to the `b--` expression. It will always start at value 4 and will stop depending on the value of `a`.

Answer (score 2):

variable `a` will go from 0 to 4, so for each iteration you will have:

```
for (b = 4; b >= 0; b--)
    { [...]

for (b = 4; b >= 1; b--)
    { [...]

for (b = 4; b >= 2; b--)
    { [...]
```

Comment: so the b-- does nothing in this case? sorry, I am new to java :(

Comment: I thought b would have new value for each loop as b-- is there and that would mean the loop would be smaller every time

Comment: @ThànhĐạt the best you can do is to write down each iteration on a paper with each variable value. You have to understand each parts of for-loop too. First is init, second is the condition before iteration and the last one is the statement executed after iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the comments in the code and you will se the difference!

```
    int a, b, c;
    for (a = 0; a < 5; a++)
    {
        for (b = 4; b >= a; b--) // Print every time b-a + 1 underscores... since you start every time with b=4 you have for each a one space fewer
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        for (c = 0; c <= a - b; c++) // and then print (a-b)-c +1 stars (b is every time a-1)... 
                                     // (first a=0 -b=-1)+1=2 and any time it will prit 2 stars scince
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    for (a = 0; a < 5; a++)
    {
        for (b = 4; b >= 0; b--) // Print every time b-a + 1=4 underscores
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        for (c = 0; c <= a - b; c++) // and then print (a-b)-c +1 stars (b is every time -1)... 
                                     // first time ( a=0 -b=-1)+1 =2 , second time (a=1 - b=-1)+1=3
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```